# OnChange event handler for radio button (INPUT type="radio") doesn't work as one value

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I'm looking for a generalized solution for this.

Consider 2 radio type inputs with the same name. When submitted, the one that is checked determines the value that gets sent with the form:

```
<input type="radio" name="myRadios" onchange="handleChange1();" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="myRadios" onchange="handleChange2();" value="2" />
```

The change event does not fire when a radio button is de-selected. So if the radio with `value="1"` is already selected and the user selects the second, `handleChange1()` does not run. This presents a problem (for me anyway) in that there is no event where I can catch this de-selection.

What I would like is a workaround for the `onChange` event for the checkbox group value or alternatively, an `onCheck` event that detects not only when a radio button is checked but also when it is unchecked.

I'm sure some of you have run into this problem before. What are some workarounds (or ideally what is the right way to handle this)? I just want to catch the change event, access the previously checked radio as well as the newly checked radio.

P.S.
`onClick` seems like a better (cross-browser) event to indicate when a radio button is checked but it still does not solve the unchecked problem.

I suppose it makes sense why `onChange` for a checkbox type does work in a case like this since it changes the value that it submits when you check or un-check it. I wish the radio buttons behaved more like a SELECT element's `onChange` but what can you do...

Answer (score 251, accepted):

```js
var rad = document.myForm.myRadios;
var prev = null;
for (var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
    rad[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
        (prev) ? console.log(prev.value): null;
        if (this !== prev) {
            prev = this;
        }
        console.log(this.value)
    });
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="radio" name="myRadios"  value="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="myRadios"  value="2" />
</form>
```

Here's a JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/crp6em1z/

Comment: Just a note on why I chose this as the correct answer: Click event handlers are set up on each of the radio buttons with the name attribute `myRadios` to read the variable `prev` which holds the currently selected radio. A comparison is done within each click handler to decide if the clicked radio is the same as the one stored in `prev` and if not then the currently clicked radio is stored there. Within the click handler, you have access to the previously selected: `prev` and the currently selected radio: `this`

Comment: It would be better to cache the function outside the loop, so that all radios share the same event handler (now they have identical handlers but they are different functions). Or maybe put all radios inside a wrapper and use event delegation

Comment: I love this example, only comment to make it better would be to call rad radios. It is picky but rad(s) usually stands for radians in most scripts these days Except for that awesome job.

Comment: Agreed. Three characters are not really worth the ambiguity.

Comment: @Oriol, or anyone knowledgeable, could you give an example of (1) caching outside the loop or (2) wrapper + event delegation ?

Comment: @MattVoda [Without optimizations](https://jsfiddle.net/f67a9ua7/). [Sharing the event listener](https://jsfiddle.net/f67a9ua7/1/). [With event delegation](https://jsfiddle.net/f67a9ua7/2/)

Comment: @Oriol What are the use cases for your 3 options? Or are they interchangeable? Thanks for taking the time to explain to a noob.

Comment: @MattVoda I wouldn't use the first, because I don't think copying the event listener for each element has any advantage. The second is like the first, but all elements share the same event listener. The third adds the event listener to a single element, but then each time an event is triggered you must check the target, and the listener won't run if some element in between stops the propagation of the event. The third is useful when new elements are inserted dynamically, otherwise the second is more simple.

Comment: Shouldn't you use something like 'onfocus' instead of 'onclick' (to catch keyboard taps as well)?

Comment: onclick doesn't work with keyboard selection, you can use `rad[i].addEventListener('change', function(){ //your handler code })` and it will work for both mouse and keyboard

Comment: @juanmi that's incorrect in my testing. `click` is fired when using the keyboard to toggle checkboxes and radio buttons.

Answer (score 166):

I would make two changes:

```
<input type="radio" name="myRadios" onclick="handleClick(this);" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="myRadios" onclick="handleClick(this);" value="2" />
```

1. Use the `onclick` handler instead of `onchange` - you're changing the "checked state" of the radio input, not the `value`, so there's not a change event happening.
2. Use a single function, and pass `this` as a parameter, that will make it easy to check which value is currently selected.

Along with your `handleClick()` function, you can track the original / old value of the radio in a page-scoped variable. That is:

```
var currentValue = 0;
function handleClick(myRadio) {
    alert('Old value: ' + currentValue);
    alert('New value: ' + myRadio.value);
    currentValue = myRadio.value;
}
```

```js
var currentValue = 0;
function handleClick(myRadio) {
    alert('Old value: ' + currentValue);
    alert('New value: ' + myRadio.value);
    currentValue = myRadio.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="myRadios" onclick="handleClick(this);" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="myRadios" onclick="handleClick(this);" value="2" />
```

Comment: Thanks, though this doesn't address the issue of having to get the previous checked radio and you are also stating something that other users have already mentioned which is to use "onclick" instead of "onchange". I actually knew this from the beginning but I wanted to draw attention to the fact that onchange doesn't work as one might expect and I would like to handle it better.

Comment: You're using JavaScript, right? So why not just maintain a variable that stores the last known selected radio button?  If you're using a single handler, then you can check for this stored value before you overwrite it with the new value. +1

Comment: @Matthew: The `onclick` handler is just named poorly -- it handles the event of radio button selection whether the button is clicked, touched, or activated by hitting "enter" on a keyboard. The `onchange` handler is not appropriate in this case since the value of the input does not change, only the checked/unchecked attribute. I've added an example script to address the previous value.

Comment: "onClick" will not handle the event if the user used the keyboard (tab + spacebar) to select the radio (and this is common practice on large forms).

Comment: +1.  "onChange()" is not a fireable event in ReactJS and this is the only solution.  Source: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1471

Comment: @HoldOffHunger As of Firefox 73.0.1 (and probably much before), using the arrow keys to select one out of several radio buttons generates an "onclick" event.

Comment: The `click` event **won't** apply on labels that are assigned to the input. Therefore is it a bad practice. When you hide the input button the function will stop working.

Answer (score 54):

As you can see from this example: http://jsfiddle.net/UTwGS/

HTML:

```
<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="my-radio">Radio One</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="2" name="my-radio">Radio One</label>
```

jQuery:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click change', function(e) {
    console.log(e.type);
});
```

both the `click` and `change` events are fired when selecting a radio button option (at least in some browsers).

I should also point out that in my example the `click` event **is still fired** when you use tab and the keyboard to select an option.

So, my point is that even though the `change` event is fired is some browsers, the `click` event should supply the coverage you need.

Comment: Yes, because there is a `console.log` statement in my code, which IE7 doesn't support. You could just alert it in IE if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't address how to get the previously selected checkbox though. Also thanks, I didn't know console.log didn't work in IE.

Comment: Don't double up on event handlers -- in browsers that fire both the `click` and `change` event handlers, you'll end up calling the handler twice. In this case, since @Matthew is concerned with the previous value, that could lead to bad consequences.

Comment: @NateCook you clearly missed the point of my example. I was showing that any time the change event is fired, the click event is also fired. Just because I was using both events in my example does not mean I was promoting it. I think your down-vote was undeserved.

Comment: But you were promoting it -- your original answer said "So, my point is that even though the change event is fired is some browsers, the click event should supply the coverage you need as a fallback, and you can use change in the browsers that support it." `click` is the correct handler here and the only one you need. Your revision clarifies that, so I'm removing my down-vote.

Comment: and to get value use `e.target.value`

Answer (score 27):

You can add the following JS script

```
<script>
    function myfunction(event) {
        alert('Checked radio with ID = ' + event.target.id);
    }
    document.querySelectorAll("input[name='myRadios']").forEach((input) => {
        input.addEventListener('change', myfunction);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It is worth noting that we can both register and unregister events. This answer is great, but in scenarios where, for example, you keep opening and closing a modal containing radio buttons - then you are registering new events over and over! This could have negative repercussions like recursively calling methods tied to these events and causing unwanted bugs and crashes. So, please also remember to `input.removeEventListener(....)` to be safe!

Answer (score 15):

What about using the change event of Jquery?

```
$(function() {
    $('input:radio[name="myRadios"]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '1') {
            alert("You selected the first option and deselected the second one");
        } else {
            alert("You selected the second option and deselected the first one");
        }
    });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f8233x20/

Comment: `$(this).val()` can also be replaced with native javascript `e.currentTarget.value`, where e is the event object passed through the callback function.

Comment: what happens if you run this multiple times for the same radio ? maybe better call `off` first ?

Answer (score 9):

**Easiest and power full way**

read only radio inputs using getAttribute

```js
document.addEventListener('input',(e)=>{

if(e.target.getAttribute('name')=="myRadios")
console.log(e.target.value)
})
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="myRadios" value="1" /> 1
<input type="radio" name="myRadios" value="2" /> 2
```

Comment: Note that this adds an event listener on all input fields...so if you have a form then this is fired every time someone types a character in any form input field or interacts with any form input field.

Answer (score 6):

Store the previous checked radio in a variable:
http://jsfiddle.net/dsbonev/C5S4B/

#### HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="myRadios" value="1" /> 1
<input type="radio" name="myRadios" value="2" /> 2
<input type="radio" name="myRadios" value="3" /> 3
<input type="radio" name="myRadios" value="4" /> 4
<input type="radio" name="myRadios" value="5" /> 5
```

#### JS

```
var changeHandler = (function initChangeHandler() {
    var previousCheckedRadio = null;

    var result = function (event) {
        var currentCheckedRadio = event.target;
        var name = currentCheckedRadio.name;

        if (name !== 'myRadios') return;

        //using radio elements previousCheckedRadio and currentCheckedRadio

        //storing radio element for using in future 'change' event handler
        previousCheckedRadio = currentCheckedRadio;
    };

    return result;
})();

document.addEventListener('change', changeHandler, false);
```

#### JS EXAMPLE CODE

```
var changeHandler = (function initChangeHandler() {
    var previousCheckedRadio = null;

    function logInfo(info) {
        if (!console || !console.log) return;

        console.log(info);
    }

    function logPrevious(element) {
        if (!element) return;

        var message = element.value + ' was unchecked';

        logInfo(message);
    }

    function logCurrent(element) {
        if (!element) return;

        var message = element.value + ' is checked';

        logInfo(message);
    }

    var result = function (event) {
        var currentCheckedRadio = event.target;
        var name = currentCheckedRadio.name;

        if (name !== 'myRadios') return;

        logPrevious(previousCheckedRadio);
        logCurrent(currentCheckedRadio);

        previousCheckedRadio = currentCheckedRadio;
    };

    return result;
})();

document.addEventListener('change', changeHandler, false);
```

Comment: Thanks. I might take the fiddle even a bit further and store the radio itself. This way when the value changes, you have a reference to the previously selected radio rather than just it's value.

Comment: @Matthew Actually the fiddle that I shared was storing the radio element and not the value only. The value was logged to show the purpose of the code but it was not stored for later usage. I'm editing the variable names to become more clarified:
previousChecked -> previousCheckedRadio,
that -> currentCheckedRadio;

Comment: Thanks. This is a good solution except for using the change event which doesn't behave properly cross-browser. If you used click instead it would be better.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is any way other then storing the previous state.
Here is the solution with jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lastSelected;
    $(function () {
        //if you have any radio selected by default
        lastSelected = $('[name="myRadios"]:checked').val();
    });
    $(document).on('click', '[name="myRadios"]', function () {
        if (lastSelected != $(this).val() && typeof lastSelected != "undefined") {
            alert("radio box with value " + $('[name="myRadios"][value="' + lastSelected + '"]').val() + " was deselected");
        }
        lastSelected = $(this).val();
    });
</script>

<input type="radio" name="myRadios" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="myRadios" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="myRadios" value="3" />
<input type="radio" name="myRadios" value="4" />
<input type="radio" name="myRadios" value="5" />
```

After thinking about it a bit more, I decided to get rid of the variable and add/remove class. Here is what I got: http://jsfiddle.net/BeQh3/2/

Comment: I thought about using a jQuery and there is definitely alot more that could be done with it. You could bind some custom events for checked and unchecked and even check for cross browser quirks. Sounds like a good idea for a plugin.

Comment: Thanks. I like jQuery but it is unavailable to me in this case.

Comment: How is jQuery unavailable to you?

Comment: If jQuery were unavailable to me, I'd find a different job.

Answer (score 6):

I realize this is an old issue, but this snippet of code works for me.  Perhaps someone in the future will find it useful:

```
<h2>Testing radio functionality</h2>
<script type="text/javascript">var radioArray=[null];</script>
<input name="juju" value="button1" type="radio" onclick="radioChange('juju','button1',radioArray);" />Button 1
<input name="juju" value="button2" type="radio" onclick="radioChange('juju','button2',radioArray);" />Button 2
<input name="juju" value="button3" type="radio" onclick="radioChange('juju','button3',radioArray);" />Button 3
<br />

<script type="text/javascript">
function radioChange(radioSet,radioButton,radioArray)
  {
  //if(radioArray instanceof Array) {alert('Array Passed');}
  var oldButton=radioArray[0];
  if(radioArray[0] == null)
    {
    alert('Old button was not defined');
    radioArray[0]=radioButton;
    }
  else
    {
    alert('Old button was set to ' + oldButton);
    radioArray[0]=radioButton;
    }
  alert('New button is set to ' + radioArray[0]);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: If you add `onkeydown="radioChange('juju','button1',radioArray);"` you could also capture when a user uses space to check the radio.

Answer (score 5):

As you can see here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp
The onchange attribute is not supported for radio buttons.

The first SO question linked by you gives you the answer: Use the `onclick` event instead and check the radio button state inside of the function it triggers.

Comment: This is just a bit incomplete. So, after creating a function to handle all the clicks in the group, how would you check to see which one has been deselected? Also, I am looking for a non-jquery solution.

Comment: The clicked radio button will be checked, all others of the same group will be unchecked. Or, your could loop through all radio buttons of that group and check their status.

If you provided more information about what you want to do with the radio buttons, it would be easier to tell you how to go on.

Comment: `onclick` is not the same semantic, as you can change the checkedness of a radio button through keyboard input given keyboard form selection being enabled.

Comment: @gsnedders onclick seems to work via keyboard input in most browsers though - Firefox, IE, Safari, Chrome. It's odd that it does what onchange is supposed to do, but it does. I'm curious how this works on mobile platforms though.

Comment: @Matthew: `onclick` is semantically weird, in that it gets fired when the radio button is either clicked with the mouse or "clicked" with the keyboard. However, `onchange` is inappropriate because the value of the input isn't being affected by the click, only the checked/unchecked state. `onchange` fires on changes to the value of other input elements.

Comment: @Nate Cook I completely agree with you.

Comment: And why is that, in your opinion?

Comment: w3schools for 1 and didn't address the whole problem for 2 which was how to get the previously selected radio. 2 was the most important part of the question in my mind.

Comment: "For radiobuttons and checkboxes, the onchange event occurs when the checked state has been changed." from your link, so it radio buttons do support onchange

Comment: You do realise that the answer is more than 8 years old, though?

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is no change event for currently selected radio button. But problem is when each radio button is taken as a separate element. Instead a radio group should be considered a single element like `select`. So change event is triggered for that group. If it is a `select` element we never worry about each option in it, but take only the selected option. We store the current value in a variable which will become the previous value, when a new option is selected. Similarly you have to use a separate variable for storing value of checked radio button.

If you want to identify the previous radio button, you have to loop on `mousedown` event.

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName("myRadios");
var val;
for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){
    if(radios[i].checked){
        val = radios[i].value;
    }
}
```

see this : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/tywx6/2/

Comment: I thought about using mousedown to check before click happened but that won't work when using space to select the radio. Maybe the focus event in place of or in addition to what you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This is just off the top of my head, but you could do an onClick event for each radio button, give them all different IDs, and then make a for loop in the event to go through each radio button in the group and find which is was checked by looking at the 'checked' attribute.  The id of the checked one would be stored as a variable, but you might want to use a temp variable first to make sure that the value of that variable changed, since the click event would fire whether or not a new radio button was checked.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="radio" name="brd" onclick="javascript:brd();" value="IN">   
<input type="radio" name="brd" onclick="javascript:brd();" value="EX">` 
<script type="text/javascript">
  function brd() {alert($('[name="brd"]:checked').val());}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid inline script, you can simply listen for a click event on the radio. This can be achieved with plain Javascript by listening to a click event on

```
for (var radioCounter = 0 ; radioCounter < document.getElementsByName('myRadios').length; radioCounter++) {
      document.getElementsByName('myRadios')[radioCounter].onclick = function() {
        //VALUE OF THE CLICKED RADIO ELEMENT
        console.log('this : ',this.value);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
<input ID="TIPO_INST-0" Name="TIPO_INST" Type="Radio" value="UNAM" onchange="convenio_unam();">UNAM

<script type="text/javascript">
            function convenio_unam(){
                if(this.document.getElementById('TIPO_INST-0').checked){
                    $("#convenio_unam").hide();
                }else{
                    $("#convenio_unam").show(); 
                }                               
            }
</script>
```

Comment: I think this should be the answer now that it is supported.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all @Leo

Answer (score 0):

```js
var rad = document.myForm.myRadios;
var prev = null;
for (var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
    rad[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
        (prev) ? console.log(prev.value): null;
        if (this !== prev) {
            prev = this;
        }
        console.log(this.value)
    });
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="radio" name="myRadios"  value="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="myRadios"  value="2" />
</form>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Answer (score -1):

This is the easiest and most efficient function to use just add as many buttons as you want to the checked = false and make the onclick event  of each radio buttoncall this function. Designate a unique number to each radio
button

```
function AdjustRadios(which) 
{
    if(which==1)
         document.getElementById("rdpPrivate").checked=false;
    else if(which==2)
         document.getElementById("rdbPublic").checked=false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For some reason, the best answer does not works for me.

I improved best answer by use

```
    var overlayType_radio = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name="radio_overlaytype"]');
```

Original best answer use:

```
      var rad = document.myForm.myRadios;
```

The others keep the same, finally it works for me.

```
var overlayType_radio = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name="radio_overlaytype"]');
                              console.log('overlayType_radio', overlayType_radio)

                              var prev = null;
                              for (var i = 0; i < overlayType_radio.length; i++) {
                                  overlayType_radio[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
                                      (prev) ? console.log('radio prev value',prev.value): null;
                                      if (this !== prev) {
                                          prev = this;
                                      }
                                      console.log('radio now value ', this.value)
                                  });
                              }
```

html is:

```
<div id='overlay-div'>
                        <fieldset>
                                <legend> Overlay Type </legend>
                                
                                <p>
                                    <label>
                                      <input class='with-gap' id='overlayType_image' value='overlayType_image' name='radio_overlaytype' type='radio' checked/>
                                      <span>Image</span> 
                                    </label>
                                </p>

                                <p>
                                  <label>
                                    <input class='with-gap' id='overlayType_tiled_image' value='overlayType_tiled_image' name='radio_overlaytype' type='radio' disabled/>
                                    <span> Tiled Image</span>   
                                </p>

                                <p>
                                  <label>
                                    <input class='with-gap' id='overlayType_coordinated_tile' value='overlayType_coordinated_tile' name='radio_overlaytype' type='radio'  disabled/>
                                    <span> Coordinated Tile</span>  
                                </p>

                                <p>
                                  <label>
                                    <input class='with-gap' id='overlayType_none' value='overlayType_none' name='radio_overlaytype' type='radio'/>
                                    <span> None </span>            
                                  </p>

                                  
                          </fieldset>
                       </div>
```

```js
 var overlayType_radio = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name="radio_overlaytype"]');
                                  console.log('overlayType_radio', overlayType_radio)

                                  var prev = null;
                                  for (var i = 0; i < overlayType_radio.length; i++) {
                                      overlayType_radio[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
                                          (prev) ? console.log('radio prev value',prev.value): null;
                                          if (this !== prev) {
                                              prev = this;
                                          }
                                          console.log('radio now value ', this.value)
                                      });
                                  }
```

```html
<div id='overlay-div'>
                            <fieldset>
                                    <legend> Overlay Type </legend>
                                    
                                    <p>
                                        <label>
                                          <input class='with-gap' id='overlayType_image' value='overlayType_image' name='radio_overlaytype' type='radio' checked/>
                                          <span>Image</span> 
                                        </label>
                                    </p>

                                    <p>
                                      <label>
                                        <input class='with-gap' id='overlayType_tiled_image' value='overlayType_tiled_image' name='radio_overlaytype' type='radio' />
                                        <span> Tiled Image</span>   
                                    </p>

                                    <p>
                                      <label>
                                        <input class='with-gap' id='overlayType_coordinated_tile' value='overlayType_coordinated_tile' name='radio_overlaytype' type='radio'  />
                                        <span> Coordinated Tile</span>  
                                    </p>

                                    <p>
                                      <label>
                                        <input class='with-gap' id='overlayType_none' value='overlayType_none' name='radio_overlaytype' type='radio'/>
                                        <span> None </span>            
                                      </p>

                                      
                              </fieldset>
                           </div>
```

[jsfiddle click here](https://jsfiddle.net/hoogw/jetmkn02/1/)

https://jsfiddle.net/hoogw/jetmkn02/1/

Answer (score -2):

```
<script>
    function radioClick(radio){
        alert()
    }
</script>

<label>Cash on delivery</label>
<input type="radio" onclick="radioClick('A')" name="payment_method" class="form-group">

<br>

<label>Debit/Credit card, GPay, Paytm etc..</label>
<input type="radio" onclick="radioClick('B')" name="payment_method" class="form-group">
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -2):

### Tl;dr

'focusout' is dispatched before the 'change' event - example:

```js
const radioName = 'radio';

// Add radios
document.body.innerHTML = `
<style>
input + label {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
</style>
<form action="#" name="example-form">
  <fieldset>
    ${Array(5).fill(null, 0, 5).map((_, i) => {
        const offsetId = i + 1;
        const id = `radio-${offsetId}`;
        return `<label for="${id}">Radio ${offsetId}</label>
        <input type="radio" name="${radioName}" id="${id}" value="${offsetId}" />`;
      }).join('\n')}
  </fieldset>
</form>
`;

const {log} = console,

    form = document.forms['example-form']; 

form.addEventListener('submit', e => e.preventDefault());

form.addEventListener('change', e => {
    const {target} = e;
    if (target.matches(`[type="radio"][name="${radioName}"]`)) {
        log(`[${e.type}]: "${target.id}" selected;  Value: ${target.value}`);
    }
});

form.addEventListener('focusout', e => {
    const {target} = e,

        soonToBePrevValue = target && target.form ? 
            target.form.elements[radioName].value : null;
    
    if (!target.matches(`[type="radio"][name="${radioName}"]`) || !soonToBePrevValue) {
        return;
    }

    // value, for '[name="radio"]', contained in form, will change after 'focusout' event
    // has completed it's bubbling stage.
    log(`[${e.type}]: previously selected radio value: ` + 
        `${soonToBePrevValue}`);
        
    // log("Soon to be \"previous\" radio: ", target);
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f95mc0nt/2/)