# I can't get the onclick attribute on radio buttons to execute javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html, function, alert

Well, as my title suggests, I'm having a little difficulty in executing javascript functions using radio buttons. I would love to have an alert box pop-up wen I select a radio button, but my code seems to ever be working against my "love(s)". Please help me out.

Here's my HTML, it isn't much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Question One</title>
    <link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "QuestionOne.css">
    <script src = "QuestionOne.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "question">
        <h1>Question One</h1>
        <p>Calculate the area of a circle or a cube</p>
        <form id = "mainForm">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Choose shape to find area</legend>
                    <label><input type = "radio" name = "shape" value = "Circle" onclick = "checkRadios()" />Circle</label>
                    <br />
                    <label><input type = "radio" name = "shape"  value = "Cube" onclick = "checkRadios()" />Cube</label>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id = "solution">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the javascript

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName("shape");
var len = radios.length;

function checkRadios()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(radios[i].checked)
        {
            alert(radios[i].getAttribute("value") + " selected.");
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like I need to add that, i am just a beginner in js and will appreciate if the help isnt too complicated. i.e, i just want basic javascript without any libraries such as jquery, as those will be too difficult for me to understand at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method.

JavaScript:

```
var currentValue = 0;
function checkRadios(myRadio) {
    alert('Old value: ' + currentValue);
    alert('New value: ' + myRadio.value);
    currentValue = myRadio.value;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type = "radio" name = "shape" value = "Circle" onclick = "checkRadios(this)" />
```

Refer to [OnChange event handler for radio button (INPUT type="radio") doesn't work as one value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838648/onchange-event-handler-for-radio-button-input-type-radio-doesnt-work-as-one)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to run in a browser with developer tools such as chrome or firefox.

Use **var** instead of **int** on that for loop.

Also, the len was 0 when I ran it. So you can check that in the loop too.

```
for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++)
{
    if(radios[i].checked)
    {
        alert(radios[i].getAttribute("value") + " selected.");
    }
}
```

see also:

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp
  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

Comment: I cant beleive I used int instead of var. Actually I can, since Im a js noob. Anyway, thank you so much. By combining your solution and that of cederlof, I have managed to get alert dialogs. Im sure I can continue on with my project now, thanks to your help. Much Obliged.