# How to disable input unless a radio button is clicked?

Tags: javascript

I'm not so familiar with Javascript and I know this to be a very easy question, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

I'm trying to disable two input fields unless a radio button with the id "custom" is selected.

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="period" value="week" /> Weekly
<input type="radio" name="period" value="fortnight" /> Fortnightly
<input type="radio" name="period" value="month" /> Monthly
<input type="radio" name="period" value="quarter" /> Quarterly
<input type="radio" name="period" value="year" /> Annually
<input type="radio" name="period" id="custom" value="one-time" onchange="datedis()"/
<input type="date" name="from" disabled /> to <input type="date" name="to" disabled />
```

**Javascript**

```
function datedis() {
    if(document.getElementsById("custom").checked) {
        document.getElementsByName("from").disabled = false;
        document.getElementsByName("to").disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementsByName("from").disabled = true;
        document.getElementsByName("to").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/54YGT/) is my code in JSFiddle.

Comment: The easy way is to have one radio button checked and the input fields always enabled.

Comment: But I want the input fields to only enable when a certain radio button is checked.

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake. You will have an answer soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple issues:

1. Use `onclick` instead of `onchange`, and make sure to assign the event handler to all radio buttons, not just *custom*, otherwise clicking away from *custom* will not disable the input field.
   See also: [OnChange event handler for radio button (INPUT type="radio") doesn't work as one value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838648/onchange-event-handler-for-radio-button-input-type-radio-doesnt-work-as-one)
2. It's `getElementById`, not `getElementsById`.
3. There's no `document.getElementByName`.
4. In jsfiddle, define a function with `window.foo = function() {...}`, not `function foo() {...}` (because that code is embedded in `onload`).

FYC: http://jsfiddle.net/MEsGH/