# Removing hover state of disabled custom radio button

Tags: html, css

I have a custom radio button using some radio button icons from Font Awesome. I have a hover state on on `.radio-spacer`, which wraps the radio button. The radio button may be in a disabled state based on some previous selections.

My problem is I want no hover state when the radio button is disabled. But, my hover styles exist on the wrapper and not the button itself and don't reflect whether the button is disabled or not. I can't use, for example, `.radio-spacer:disabled` as it's just the div wrapping the button and has no disabled state. Any ideas?

```css
.radio-spacer {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 103px;
}

.radio-spacer label {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.radio-spacer:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.radio-spacer:hover span {
  color: #fff;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]~span {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"]:disabled~span {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  color: #aeaeae !important;
  opacity: .65;
}

input[type="radio"]+.fa-dot-circle-o:before {
  content: "\f10c";
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+.fa-dot-circle-o:before {
  content: "\f192";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="radio-spacer">
  <label>
        <input type="radio" class="hide select-plan" name="select-plan" />
        <span class="fa fa-fw fa-dot-circle-o"></span><span class="radio-label">Select</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio-spacer">
  <label>
        <input type="radio" class="hide select-plan" name="select-plan" disabled />
        <span class="fa fa-fw fa-dot-circle-o"></span><span class="radio-label">Disabled</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: add information to your component, e.g `<div class="radio-spacer is-disabled">` and use that for your styling.

Comment: Please include the compiled CSS rather than the Sass.

Comment: Is this what you need?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073968/how-to-disable-input-unless-a-radio-button-is-clicked

Comment: Is this what you need?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073968/how-to-disable-input-unless-a-radio-button-is-clicked

Answer (score 2):

You can make the hover style with an empty `<span>` element and place it after the radio/checkbox or use an `:after` pseudo element, example below. You will need javascripts otherwise to check the radio/checkbox status and add a class to the container then style it.

```css
.radio-spacer {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  position: relative;
}

.select-plan:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.select-plan:disabled ~ .radio-label {
  color: silver;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.select-plan:not([disabled]):hover:after {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-spacer">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" class="hide select-plan" name="select-plan" />
    <span class="radio-label">Select</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio-spacer">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" class="hide select-plan" name="select-plan" disabled />
    <span class="radio-label">Disabled</span>
  </label>
</div>
```