# onclick event not fired on clicking

Tags: javascript

i am facing a weired small issue.. the onclick action of radio button is not executed. i tried with onchange event as well, but of no use..

```
   <label><input type="radio" name="search_type" id="search_type" value="name" onchange="by_name()">Enter the Name </label> 
  <input name="tag" type="text" id="search" maxlength="30">                       
  <label><input type="radio" name="search_type" id="search_type" value="all" onchange="all()">All</label>
```

and on clicking All,

```
  function all()
   {
       window.alert('hi');
    }
```

can you help me with your suggestions.. (the js file is linked as well)

Comment: Try add `onclick` to label. `Onclick` should work on `radiobutton`. Maybe function write after handling event.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838648/onchange-event-handler-for-radio-button-input-type-radio-doesnt-work-as-one

Comment: why to id with same name??

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It does work with `all` [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/LzbA2/1/)

First, you are using two different inputs with the same id. You can't do that.

Second, try seperating your HTML from JS : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/LzbA2/)

**HTML:**

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="search_type" id="search_type" value="name">Enter the Name</label>
<input name="tag" type="text" id="search" maxlength="30">
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="search_type" id="search_type2" value="all">All</label>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var input1 = document.getElementById('search_type');
var input2 = document.getElementById('search');
var input3 = document.getElementById('search_type2');

input1.onclick = function(){
    alert('input1');
};
input2.onclick = function(){
    alert('input2');
};
input3.onclick = function(){
    alert('input3');
};
```

**Why seperate them?**

It's modern and if you have a lot of HTML it's easier to read your javascript if you have it in a seperate file.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() 
        {

            $('body').click(function()
            {
                alert('hi');
            });
         });
```

here change the "body" tag to the ID of the object you want to have the function happen on.
**make sure you are using Jquery otherwise this wont work**

Comment: not working... the control doesn't go in there... be it javascript or jquery :(

Comment: try again. i didnt clode the document ready function at first. @SamuelMathews

Answer (score -1):

Rename the function. `all` has a predefined meaning in many browsers making it (effectively, if not actually) a reserved keyword when used with in an intrinsic event attribute.

[Non-working version](http://jsbin.com/lezucowa/1/) gives "NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE: Illegal value".

[Working version](http://jsbin.com/lezucowa/2/) has `all` renamed to `notall`.