# Change radio button value to the value of text input

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have this code which has a radio button. I want to get the value of the text box and set it as the value of the selected radio button.

HTML

```
<form action="add.php" id="registration" method="post" name='registration'
onsubmit="return formValidation();">
    Monthly amount of<br>
    <input id="300" name="amounts" type="radio" value="300"><label for="300">P
    300.00</label><br>
    <input id="amntother" name="amounts" type="radio" value="">P
    <input disabled="disabled" id="otherAmount" name="amntotherSpecify" type=
    "text" value=""><label for="amntother">(please specify)</label><br>
    <button name="submit" style="width:305px" type="submit" value=
    "Submit">ADD</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
window.onload = function() {
    var promised = document.getElementsByName("amounts");
    for (var i = 0; i < promised.length; i++) {
        promised[i].onclick = function() {
            var rads = this.form[this.name];
            for (var i = 0; i < rads.length; i++) {
                var textField = this.form[rads[i].value.toLowerCase() + "Amount"];
                if (textField) textField.disabled = !rads[i].checked;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838648/onchange-event-handler-for-radio-button-input-type-radio-doesnt-work-as-one

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do. The question says you want to set the value of the radio button, but where are you assigning anything to the value?

Comment: the first button has the value of 300. and i want the value of the second button will be coming from the text box.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <form form="view" name='registration' method="POST"  action="add.php" onSubmit="return formValidation();">  
    Monthly amount of</br>
    <input type="radio" name="amounts" id="300" value="300"  ><label for="300">P 300.00</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="amounts" id="amntother" value=""   >P<br/>
    <input type="text" name="amntotherSpecify" id="otherAmount" value=""  onchange="addValueToRadioBtn();"/><label for="amntother">(please specify)</label><br/>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="width:305px">ADD</button>
```

```
<script>  
function addValueToRadioBtn() {
    if (document.getElementById("amntother").checked == true){
        document.getElementById("amntother").value = document.getElementById("otherAmount").value;
    }
    //added an alert box just to test that the value has been updated
    alert(document.getElementById("amntother").value);
} 

</script>
```

I have removed the disabled value so that a value can be entered, on change of this value and if the radio button (otheramount) is selected then other amount value will reflect the value that was entered in the textbox.

Just to note that if you disable the text then no user will be able to add a value. If this isn't what you are looking for could you explain in more detail as to how the textbox will be populated and more in what you are trying to achieve.

Anyway hope this script helps

Comment: i made a function there that if you click that button it will automatically enables the textbox.

Comment: i had this php code.. otherAmount if it is clicked?

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","Balibolista.7");
mysql_select_db("adding", $con);
@$fullname=$_POST['name'];
@$amnt=$_POST['amounts'];
if(@$_POST['submit'])
{
$sql="insert into amount(name,money) values('$fullname','$amnt')";
mysql_query($sql);
}
?>

Comment: i had this php code.. otherAmount if it is clicked?

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","Balibolista.7");
mysql_select_db("adding", $con);
@$fullname=$_POST['name'];
@$amnt=$_POST['amounts'];
if(@$_POST['submit'])
{
$sql="insert into amount(name,money) values('$fullname','$amnt')";
mysql_query($sql);
}
?>

Comment: ok, so the function that enables the textbox will solve that problem and the code I have put up will do the trick for the changing the radio button value. WIs my code going to solve the problem for you?

Comment: yes. but i'm having a hard time storing the value of amntother to my db

Comment: I don't really use PHP anymore as moved over to asp.net, however this line doesn't look right  values('$fullname','$amnt')";   you have included apostrophes so the script is going to read the vairables as strings and not as they are intended try this - values($fullname,$amnt)";

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify `formValidation` or add.php. If all you want to do is add the specified value as an option, you don't need to call back to the server to do that. Just update the form with the new option:

#### html

```
<form form="view" name='registration' method="post" action="add.php" onsubmit="return formValidation();">  
    <div id="amountOptions">
        Monthly amount of</br>
        <input type="radio" name="amounts" id="opt300" value="300" ><label for="opt300">P 300.00</label><br/>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="amntotherSpecify" id="newvalue" value=""/>
    <input type="button" id="btnNewValue" value="Specify your own amount"/>
</form>
```

### javascript

```
var btnNewValue = document.getElementById('btnNewValue');
btnNewValue.addEventListener('click', function()
{
    var div = document.getElementById('amountOptions');
    var newAmount = document.forms[0].amntotherSpecify.value;

    var optCheck = document.getElementById('opt'+newAmount);
    if(optCheck !== null)
        return;

    var newopt = document.createElement('input');
    newopt.type = 'radio';
    newopt.id = 'opt'+newAmount;
    newopt.name = 'amounts';
    newopt.value = newAmount;

    var newoptLabel = document.createElement('label');
    newoptLabel.for = newopt.id;
    newoptLabel.innerHTML = 'P ' + newAmount;

    var br = document.createElement('br');

    div.appendChild(newopt);
    div.appendChild(newoptLabel);
    div.appendChild(br);

    var newAmount = document.forms[0].amntotherSpecify.value = '';
});
```

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qM4L/2/) to demonstrate it in action. You'll want to add in validation that the new option's value is a number and fits whatever constraints you have.

It's important that you note that according to the html spec, ids cannot start with a number, in fact they must start with a character in the range `a-zA-Z`.

Answer (score 0):

how about this option...

Slight modification to HTML - extra button, extra label tag

HTML

```
<form form="view" name='registration' method="POST"  action="add.php" onSubmit="return formValidation();">  
    Monthly amount of</br>
    <input type="radio" name="amounts" id="300" value="300" ><label for="300">P 300.00</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="amounts" id="amntother" value="" ><label id="labelamntother" for="amntother">P</label>
    <input type="text" name="amntotherSpecify" id="otherAmount" value=""  /><label for="amntother">(please specify)</label><br/>
    <button type="button" name="reset" value="Reset Value" style="width:305px" onclick="location.reload(true)">Reset Radio Button Value</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="width:305px">ADD</button>
    </form>
```

Javascript

```
   <script>
    document.getElementById("otherAmount").onkeyup = function() {
       document.getElementById("labelamntother").innerHTML ="P " + this.value;   
    }
     </script>
```