# How to run a function from radio button mouseup event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use a pair of radio buttons to start/stop an automated horizontal scroller.  I've tried several jquery techniques that I found on SO, but I haven't been able to get them to work.

Here's my latest attempt:

```
$( "#radAutoScroll0" ).mouseup(function() {
    scrollTimer(); 
});
function scrollTimer(){
    if($("#radAutoScroll0").is(':checked')){
        // scroller code.....
    }
}

<div class="scrollDiv">
    <label for="autoScroll" class="autoScrollLabel">Auto Scroll</label><br />
    <label for="radAutoScroll0" class="labAutoScroll">
        <input type='radio' name='radAutoScroll' id='radAutoScroll0' class="rad1" checked="checked" value='on'/>On
    </label>
    <label for="radAutoScroll1" class="labAutoScroll">
        <input type='radio' name='radAutoScroll' id='radAutoScroll1' class="rad1" value='off'/>Off
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: jsfiddle/plnkr/codepen please?

Comment: why not use .click()?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838648/onchange-event-handler-for-radio-button-input-type-radio-doesnt-work-as-one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `change` event, and bind it to both radio buttons (using the `labAutoScroll` class) so it fires when you click either of them.

```
$('.labAutoScroll').change(function()
{
    if($("#radAutoScroll0").is(':checked')){
        // scroller code.....
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Or try to use 'click' event on your label as they wrap the radio-button:

```
$(document).on('click', '.labAutoScroll', function(event) {

    var thisButton = $(this).prop('for');

    if (thisButton == 'radAutoScroll0') {


    } else {


    }

});
```

If you have more than 2 radio buttons you can use `switch(thisButton)` to separate your cases.