# how to add eventListener on radio inputs

Tags: javascript

I have this code, it works correctly, but at first instant of `document.myform.onchange` I tried `document.myform.elem.onclick` and this last code doesn't want to work, it only first when I put it on a form, why it's happening?

```
<form name="myform">
            <input type="radio" name="car" value="audi">audi<br>
            <input type="radio" name="car" value="bmw">bmw
            <div id="text">some text is here</div>
 </form>

function ready() {
    var elem = document.getElementsByName("car");
    var hid = document.getElementById("text");
    var i;

    document.myform.onchange = function() {
       for (i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
            if (elem[0].checked == true) {
                hid.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                hid.style.display = "block";
            }
        } 
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please state your intention clearly.

Comment: Attach `onchange` on radio buttons, not on `form`

Comment: I don't get the purpose of jQuery tag here?!

Comment: elem is not a DOMElement and it makes no sense trying to listen for click event on document.myform.elem.onclick... Then it should be elem[i] in the loop I think...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OnChange event handler for radio button (INPUT type="radio") doesn't work as one value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838648/onchange-event-handler-for-radio-button-input-type-radio-doesnt-work-as-one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Register `change` event over `radio` buttons(in a loop) than `form`
- Instead of dealing with `index` of `radio-input`, check the value of checked radio button

```js
function ready() {
  var elem = document.getElementsByName("car");
  var hid = document.getElementById("text");
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    elem[i].onchange = function() {
      if (this.value === 'audi') {
        hid.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        hid.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

```html
<form name="myform">
  <input type="radio" name="car" value="audi">audi
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="car" value="bmw">bmw
  <div id="text">some text is here</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can inspire from these example , good luck

```
<form name="myForm">
                <input type="radio" name="car"  value="1" />
                <input type="radio" name="car"  value="2" />
            </form>

    <script>
    var rad = document.myForm.car;
    var prev = null;
    for(var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
        rad[i].onclick = function() {
            (prev)? console.log(prev.value):null;
            if(this !== prev) {
                prev = this;
            }
            console.log(this.value)
        };
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a `change` event to your radio inputs like this:

```
function ready() {
    var radioInputs = document.myform.car,
        hid = document.getElementById("text");
    for(var i = 0; i < radioInputs.length; i++){
        radioInputs[i].onchange = function() {
            hid.style.display = radioInputs[0].checked ? 'block' : 'none';
        };
    }
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

```js
function ready() {
 var radioInputs = document.myform.car,
        hid = document.getElementById("text");
 for(var i = 0; i < radioInputs.length; i++){
     radioInputs[i].onchange = function() {
         hid.style.display = radioInputs[0].checked ? 'block' : 'none';
     };
    }
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

```html
<form name="myform">
            <input type="radio" name="car" value="audi">audi<br>
            <input type="radio" name="car" value="bmw">bmw
            <div id="text">some text is here</div>
 </form>
```