# How to have a radio button set a js variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I want to figure out how to change a JavaScript variable to a certain value when a HTML radio button is selected.  Then I want to put the variable into local storage so I can put it on other pages of my site.

This is what I have so far:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var radioArray = [null];
</script>
<input name="b1" value="button1" type="radio" onclick="radioChange('b1','1',radioArray);" />Button 1
<input name="b2" value="button2" type="radio" onclick="radioChange('b2','2',radioArray);" />Button 2
<input name="b3" value="button3" type="radio" onclick="radioChange('b3','3',radioArray);" />Button 3
<br />

<script type="text/javascript">
  function radioChange(radioSet, radioButton, radioArray) {}
</script>
```

Comment: [Maybe this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8997289/2925210) just change onclick closure

Comment: *"I want to figure out"* - Hmm... Do you?

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is here? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

**Not sure with what you wanted but radio button can be selected only one at a time and for that 'name' attribute should be same**