# form enable by input radio id (checked)

Tags: javascript

I have two forms. I want one of them to be enabled by the user choose through one of the radio buttons above.

What I want to do is to get the value of radio button and through this value make one of the forms enable.

So I try with JavaScript and input radio ID but I had no success:

```js
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', init);
    function init(){
        var radio = document.getElementsByName ("questions");
            for (var i=0; i<radios.length; i++) {
            if(radio[i].getElementById.checked == "questions_1") {
            radio[i].addEventListener(seleccionar);  
        }
    }

    function trigger() {
        elementsForm = document.forms['question'].elements;
        for (var y=0; y<elementsForm.length; y++) {
        elementsForm[y].disabled=false;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Here's my code (HTML and CSS):

```css
.category_1 {
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 2%;
}

.question {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

.q-text {
    font-weight: 600;
}

.q1 {
    width: 44%;
}

.q2 {
    width: 44%;
}

.form {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

.form.q1 {
    width: 44%;
}

.form.q2 {
    width: 44%;
}

.data {
    margin-top: 5%;
}

.data label {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 100%; 
}

select {
    width: 100%;
}

textarea {
    width: 98%;
}

input[type=submit] {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
  <body>

<div class="category_1">

    <div class="question q1"><input type="radio" name="question" value="question_1" id="question_1">
    <div class="q-text">QUESTION 1</div></div>

    <div class="question q2"><input type="radio" name="question" value="question_2" id="question_2">
    <div class="q-text">QUESTION 2</div></div>

</div>

<div class="form q1">
<form name="q1" method="post" action="">

<div class ="data">
    <label for="others">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" disabled>     
</div>

<div class="data">
        <label for="others">Select an item:</label>
        <select name="items-q1" disabled>
            <option value="it1">item 1</option>
            <option value="it2">item 2</option>
            <option value="it3">item 3</option>
            <option value="it4">item 4</option>
        </select>
</div>

<div class="data">
        <label for="others">Anything else?</label>
        <textarea name="more" disabled></textarea>
</div>

<div class="data">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" disabled>
</div>
</form>
</div>


<div class="form q2">
    <form name="q2" method="post" action="">

<div class ="data">
    <label for="others">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" disabled>    
</div>

<div class ="data">
<label for="others">Choose an option:</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="o1" disabled><label for="others">1</label>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="o2" disabled><label for="others">2</label>     
</div>    


<div class="data">
        <label for="others">Anything else?</label>
        <textarea name="more" disabled></textarea>
</div>    


<div class="data">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" disabled>
</div>
</form>
</div> 
</body>
```

I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i noticed your are getting the radios by the wrong name
its "question" not "questions"

```
<script>
    var rad = document.getElementsByName('question');
    for(var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
        rad[i].onclick = function() {
        if(this.value == "questions_1") {
        //input logic to display form
        //This is where you run isTrue() Function
           isTrue(data);
        }
        else{
         //This is where you run isFalse() function
         isFalse(data);
        }
          };
        }
//Function to run if its true
    function isTrue(data){
       //something equals something
    }

//Function to run if its false
function isFalse(data){
   //something equals something
}
</script>
```

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838648/onchange-event-handler-for-radio-button-input-type-radio-doesnt-work-as-one)

Comment: This works, but how I can add a function inside the code to be executed if the condition is true? e.g.

Comment: `<script>
var disabled = function dis(name) {
    var select = document.querySelectorAll("name");
    for (var i = 0; i<select.length; i++) {
        select[i].disabled = false;
    }
}
var rad = document.getElementsByName('question');
for(var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
    rad[i].onclick = function () {
        if(this.value == "question_1") {
            function dis(data);
        }
    };
}       
</script>    `

Comment: The if runs when its true and the else runs when its false. I have edited the answer to make it clear.

Comment: Here I go. I insert the code above. I've been watching reference link to enable/disable multiple inputs through a checked event.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
var rad = document.getElementsByName('question');
for(var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
    rad[i].onclick = function () {
        if(this.value == "question_1") {
        e1();
        }else {
        e2();    
        }
    };
}
    
function e1() {
    var eform1 = document.querySelectorAll('.q1 input[type=text], .q1 select, .q1 textarea, .q1 input[type=submit]');
    for(var i = 0; i < eform1.length; i++) {
    eform1[i].disabled = false;
    }
}
    
function e2() {
    var eform2 = document.querySelectorAll('.q2 input[type=text], .q2 input[type=radio], .q2 textarea, .q2 input[type=submit]');
    for(var i = 0; i < eform2.length; i++) {
    eform2[i].disabled = false;
    }
}    
</script>
```