# onChange or onClick for Radio buttons and Check boxes in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the best practice for handling events on Radio Buttons and Check boxes in ReactJS?  The documentation shows using "[onClick](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html)" on the "Handling Events" documentation and it shows using "[onChange](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html)" in the "Forms" documentation.  onChange only fires one time on Radio Buttons, so I am currently using onClick for them.  I assume this is a bug.

Comment: Regarding radio buttons, check out [Radio Input onChange only fires once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45450285/radio-input-onchange-only-fires-once)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heyo, It's not a bug it is because in some cases you only want to know when it changes. For example, when you have an API that supports patch so you can send modifications on every change.

If your API only support submitting all at once the **onClick** is right for you!

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons respond to both `onchange` and `onclick` events in JavaScript. However, the onchange event may not work as you would expect it. The `onchange` event is not triggered when turning a radio button on and off but only one or the other.

Most browsers trigger `onchange` when the radio button is selected, but Internet Explorer prior to version 9 triggers `onchange` when the radio button is deselected.

Comment: See a demo of this in action [here](https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/radio/onclick-onchange.php).