# React rendering previous array state (sorting)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, sorting, state

Basically im developing a component where i use the .map method in an array stored in a state and render another component for each occurrence of that array, besides that im making a component that sorts the array according to some parameters using the .sort method

The problem im facing is that my component is rendering the previous state of the array, so if i sort it by a parameter and then sort it by another parameter, the array showing rendered on the screen is the one sorted by the first parameter, just like that:

(likes = sort by highest green number | deslikes = sort by highest red number)

[image]

The code:

- Component rendering the array

```html
export default function Piadas() {
  const [searchBarContent, setSearchBarContent] = useState("");
  const [order, setOrder] = useState("");
  const [jokes, setJokes] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    if(jokes.length == 0)
      fetchData("getJokes");
  }, [jokes])

  function fetchData(url) {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3006/${url}`)
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        setJokes(data.data);
      });
  }

  
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Só piada boa</title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Aplicação utilizando Banco de dados, CRUD, REST e Next.JS"
        />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main>
        <ContainerStageBackgroundPiadas>
          <LightBrownMobileWrapper>
            <UtilsWrapper
              searchBarContent={searchBarContent}
              setSearchBarContent={setSearchBarContent}
              order={order}
              setOrder={setOrder}
              jokes={jokes}
              setJokes={setJokes}
            />
            <CardWrapper>
            
            {
            jokes
            .map((data) => (
              <Card data={data} key={uuidv4()} />
            ))
            }
            </CardWrapper>
          </LightBrownMobileWrapper>
        </ContainerStageBackgroundPiadas>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

- Popover component that orders onChange of the input:

  ```
  export default function Popover({order, setOrder, jokes, setJokes}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if(order === "likes")
      setJokes(jokes.sort((a, b) => (a.likes < b.likes ? 1 : -1)))
    else if(order === "dislikes")
      setJokes(jokes.sort((a, b) => (a.dislikes < b.dislikes ? 1 : -1)))

  console.log(jokes);
  }, [order, jokes, setJokes])

  return (
    <PopoverContainer style={{width: "100%"}}>
        <PopoverTrigger>
        Ordenar
        </PopoverTrigger>
        <PopoverContent>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="orderRadio" value="likes" onChange={(event) => setOrder(event.target.value)} />
                <p>Likes</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="orderRadio" value="dislikes" onChange={(event) => setOrder(event.target.value)} />
                <p>Deslikes</p>
            </div>
        </PopoverContent>
    </PopoverContainer>
  )
  ```

  }

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45450285/radio-input-onchange-only-fires-once) may be worth looking at. Main 2 points: try setting the "checked" property for each input and try using onClick instead of onChange.

Comment: got the same results trying this @Rylee, besides that it gave me a new error saying that i cant use onClick on input type=radio without onChange, "You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. "

Comment: Hmm, maybe React handles it differently now. Can you include the `UtilsWrapper` component code? I'd assume it's being passed through directly to the `Popover` but it also seems to make sense as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the way i was doing the sort, i was changing the state directly and then doing the map on that state, now that state remains with his original value and then i make the .sort directly in his original value on the render, maybe react doenst handle well the first way (sorting the value of the state i was mapping), anyway this looks way better now:

```html
  function sortParams(a, b){
    if(order === "likes"){
      return a.likes < b.likes ? 1 : -1
    }
    else if(order === "dislikes")
      return a.dislikes < b.dislikes ? 1 : -1
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Só piada boa</title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Aplicação utilizando Banco de dados, CRUD, REST e Next.JS"
        />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main>
        <ContainerStageBackgroundPiadas>
          <LightBrownMobileWrapper>
            <UtilsWrapper
              searchBarContent={searchBarContent}
              setSearchBarContent={setSearchBarContent}
              order={order}
              setOrder={setOrder}
            />
            <CardWrapper>
            {
              jokes
              .sort(sortParams)
              .filter(filterParams)
              .map((data) => (
                <Card data={data} key={uuidv4()} />
              ))
            }
            </CardWrapper>
          </LightBrownMobileWrapper>
        </ContainerStageBackgroundPiadas>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should remember that `sort` modify the original values so you could simply get a copy of the `jokes` by either `[...jokes]` or `jokes.slice()`