# Remove class name from deselected radio button

Tags: javascript

I have a list of radio buttons.

```
<input type="radio" name="capital" value="bratislava">
<input type="radio" name="capital" value="kiev">
<input type="radio" name="capital" value="prague">
```

On radio button event listener type `change` I add some `class` name like this.

```
// Scope toggles
var toggles = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');

// Accesses the toggles length property outside the loop and make the loop run faster
var tL = toggles.length;

// Loop-in for `toggles` length HTML collection
for (var i = 0; i < tL; i++) {

    // Store array-like objects in this variable
    var currentToggle = toggles[i];

    // Run event listener method on `change` and refer to element using `this` keyword
    currentToggle.addEventListener('change', function() {

        // + ADD CLASS NAME
        // Check if element is checked and if className isn't present
        if ( this.checked && !this.className.match(/(?:^|\s)class(?!\S)/) ) {
            // Add class name without removing/affecting existing values
            this.className += " class";
        }

        // - REMOVE CLASS NAME
        else {
            // Replace class with empty string
            this.className = this.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)class(?!\S)/g , '' );
        }

    })

}
```

This works well on checkboxes elements but not on radio buttons group.
The goal is in the title in this question.

To solve it I assume I should set another loop within if statement and loop for all unchecked radios and remove the class?

Comment: Add a listener on "click" event for radio buttons, not on "change".

Comment: Radio buttons support only two events: `change` and `input`.

Comment: This seems an issue closer to yours. HAve a look; hope it's helping ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838648/onchange-event-handler-for-radio-button-input-type-radio-doesnt-work-as-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following the post [[OnChange event handler for radio button (INPUT type="radio") doesn't work as one value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838648/onchange-event-handler-for-radio-button-input-type-radio-doesnt-work-as-one]) mentioned in the comments, you can do it without looping through the inputs.

```js
// Scope toggles
var toggles = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');

// Accesses the toggles length property outside the loop and make the loop run faster
var tL = toggles.length;
var last = undefined;
// Loop-in for `toggles` length HTML collection
for (var i = 0; i < tL; i++) {

    // Store array-like objects in this variable
    var currentToggle = toggles[i];

    // Run event listener method on `change` and refer to element using `this` keyword
    currentToggle.addEventListener('change', function() {
   
        // + ADD CLASS NAME to current
        // Check if element is checked and if className isn't present
        if ( this.checked && !this.className.match(/(?:^|\s)class(?!\S)/) ) {
            // Add class name without removing/affecting existing values
            this.className += " class";
        }

if(last === undefined){
  last = this;
  return;
}
        // - REMOVE CLASS NAME
        else {
            // Replace class with empty string
            last.className = last.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)class(?!\S)/g , '' );
last = this;
        }

    })

}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="capital" value="bratislava">bratislava
<input type="radio" name="capital" value="kiev">kiev
<input type="radio" name="capital" value="prague">prague
```

Comment: when deselected the class isn't removed

Comment: @DomK, updated the answer. Was not updating the last reference.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah adding **second loop** will solve your probleme

```js
var varName = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
for (var i = 0; i < varName.length; i++) varName[i].onchange = functionName;

function functionName() {
  for (var i = 0; i < varName.length; i++) {
    if (varName[i] == this) varName[i].classList.add('selected');
    else varName[i].classList.remove('selected');
  }
}
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="capital" value="bratislava">
<input type="radio" name="capital" value="kiev">
<input type="radio" name="capital" value="prague">
```

Comment: For sake of simplicity If there is no need for the loop like in the accepted answer I/Browsers rather prefer it without if possible. Great answer though.