# How to detect and use a radio button deselect

Tags: javascript

I have a quiz that is based on the point system, each radio button is stored in an array, which I am looping through. Depending on what radio is selected for each question, the user gains a certain amount of points based on that radio's value. Problem is, I want to be able to remove the points for the radio if the user changes his/her minds and deselects a radio/changes answer.

```
for (var i = 0; i < allRadios.length; i++) {
  allRadios[i].addEventListener('change', (e)=>{
    let radio = e.target;
    if (radio.checked) {
      totalScoreMain = totalScoreMain + parseInt(radio.getAttribute('value'));
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: add a code snippet for better assist.

Comment: You want to subtract something from `totalScoreMain` if `radio.checked` is false?

Comment: Yes, subtract from the total score, if the radio is deselected, I want those points taken back.

Comment: try `else if (radio.checked == false)` or `else` condition to subtract the value

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838648/onchange-event-handler-for-radio-button-input-type-radio-doesnt-work-as-one

Comment: @09eric09 you can collect the checked radio buttons like in answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simply collect all the checked radio buttons inside the `change` function and then calculate the values for those checked radio buttons:

```js
var totalScoreMain = 0,
  allRadios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
for (var i = 0; i < allRadios.length; i++) {
  allRadios[i].addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    totalScoreMain = 0;
    let checkedRadios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked');
    checkedRadios.forEach(function(checkedRadio) {
      totalScoreMain += parseInt(checkedRadio.getAttribute('value'));
    });
    console.log(totalScoreMain);
  });
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input name='1_1' type="radio" value="10"> 10
  <input name='1_1' type="radio" value="20"> 20
</div>
<div>
  <input name='1_2' type="radio" value="30"> 30
  <input name='1_2' type="radio" value="40"> 40
  <input name='1_2' type="radio" value="50"> 50
</div>
<div>
  <input name='1_3' type="radio" value="35"> 35
  <input name='1_3' type="radio" value="45"> 45
  <input name='1_3' type="radio" value="25"> 25
</div>
```

Comment: Same problem, this still does not subtract the value from the total score if I uncheck a radio / change my answer.

Comment: @09eric09 the above example is working fine. Post your actual code with HTML

Comment: You're right, my mistake, it's working properly. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Turns out I declared the totalScoreMain variable outside the loop, but did not include it inside the loop. Would you mind elaborating on why the value is not subtracted if I take the totalScoreMain variable out of the loop?