# On Radio Button execute onChange function

Tags: javascript, ajax, onchange

ive got the (working) following code

```
$('#selBookable').change(function () {...
```

and

```
 <div class="radio radio-search">
  <label><input id="radio-new-pop" type="radio" name="radio_newest_popular" value="new" >Neueste</label>
```

which executes when #selBookable gets another value.

Now i want to execute this function when a Radio button somewhere else is clicked.

i tried :

```
$('#selBookable, #radio-new-pop').change(function () {...
```

but that does not work.
now i thought about giving this ".change(function NAMEHERE" 
a name and execute that function but doesnt work either.
any help is appreciated.

edit: i tried using the onchange event but then again i have no function name to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the function independently of its use, giving it a name.  Then you could attach it to as many targets you wish, making a call as the one that works (using the name instead of the definition), each with a different target.

(The reason your second attempt didn't work is that the second argument to `$` is not another target to attach the function to, but a constraint on where to find the first target.)

Comment: I figured, thats why i tried the following:

    $('#selBookable').change(name);

    $('#radio-new-pop').change(name);


    function name() {


the first one works, second doesnt.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try putting the jquery listener inside of a `$(document).ready()`.

OR

You could add a `click` handler on the radio, like this:

```
    <div class="radio radio-search">
        <label>
            <input id="radio-new-pop" type="radio" name="radio_newest_popular" value="new" onclick="handleClick(this)">
        Neueste</label>
```

and in the JS:

```
    handleClick(myRadio) {
        // click function logic
    }
```

Adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838648/onchange-event-handler-for-radio-button-input-type-radio-doesnt-work-as-one) answer.

Comment: you could also do `onclick="this.onchange"` by the way

Answer (score 1):

You have two buttons radio with the same name :

```
<div class="radio radio-search">
    <label>
        <input id="radio-new-pop" type="radio" name="radio_newest_popular" value="new" />
        Neueste
    </label>
    <label>
        <input id="radio-new-pop2" type="radio" name="radio_newest_popular" value="new" />
        Other
    </label>
</div>
```

Add a javascript function to handle this change :

```
var onRadioButtonChange = void 0;
{
    onRadioButtonChange = function (e) {
        theFunctionYouWantToExecute(); // pass this or e.target if needed
        return false;
    }
}
```

Attach it to your elements :

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]'), 
    function (element) { 
        element.addEventListener('change', onRadioButtonChange, false); 
    }
);
```