# Radio Buttons onChange event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, dom

Let's assume whe have two radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" value="val1" name="radio1" onChange="change()"/>
<input type="radio" value="val2" name="radio1" onChange="change()" />
```

Now if any of the radio buttons are clicked change() function gets executed.
So, My question is let's assume radio1 is selected and if radio2 gets selected change() function gets executed only once. Here tha value of radio1 is also being changed and radio2 also gets changed. Why not the change() function doesn't gets executed twice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838648/onchange-event-handler-for-radio-button-input-type-radio-doesnt-work-as-one This looks like a very similar question

Comment: Because the change event does not fire when a radio button is de-selected, only when it is selected. I know, seems weird because it has 'changed' but that's the nature of onChange().

Comment: This helps you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Comment: I disagree with the decision to close this as a duplicate. The question referenced is for jquery and all the answers are in jquery. This question is about vanilla javascript. Whoever closed it made a mistake. The question in the comments and the MDN reference are far more apropos

Answer (score 1):

the way you have it written radio1 and radio2 are different variables. So when you click on one of them only that one is changing.

However, if you rename them both to radio1 when you click on 1 of them only radio1 is changing as there is no other variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is how radio buttons are designed to work. According to [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#radio-button-state-typeradio), only a single `input` and `change` event is fired on the radio button in the radio button group.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) states this is another way:

> Depending on the kind of element being changed and the way the user
> interacts with the element, the `change` event fires at a different
> moment:
>
> - When the element is `:checked` (by clicking or using the keyboard) for
>   `<input type="radio">` and `<input type="checkbox">`;

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with javascript with out the need of an attribute for `onchange` in your input tag. Simply run the element list through a loop and use the key word this. Make sure each input has the same selector, i use class in my example...

Below I define the elements using `querySelectorAll()` and added a class to each radio button. I then run the element list through a for loop and apply an onchange event with in javascriot to the element. Then to get the unique one the user is changing to you use `this.value` to get the value.

```js
var matches = document.querySelectorAll('.chngRadio');

for (match in matches) {
  matches[match].onchange = function() {
    console.log(this.value)
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" class="chngRadio" name="radio" value="val1">
  <label for="val1">val1</label>
  <input type="radio" class="chngRadio" name="radio" value="val2">
  <label for="val2">val2</label>
  <input type="radio" class="chngRadio" name="radio" value="val3">
  <label for="val3">val3</label>
  <input type="radio" class="chngRadio" name="radio" value="val4">
  <label for="val4">val4</label>

</div>
```

Another way would be to create a nodeList byb querying the elements using ***`querySelectorAll('.class-name')`***. Then iterate over the elements and add an eventListener that listens for a change event. Pass the event to your callback function and handle it however you wish using ***`event.target.value`***

```js
// returns a NodeList representing a list of the document's 
// elements that match the specified group of selectors
const matches = document.querySelectorAll('.chngRadio');

// callback function that passes the event 
// use event.target.value to get the 
// value of the radio that has changed
const getSelectedValue = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
}

// iterate through the nodeList using .forEach() method
// attach an eventListener with a callback function
matches.forEach(match => {
  match.addEventListener('change', getSelectedValue);
})
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" class="chngRadio" name="radio" value="val1">
  <label for="val1">val1</label>
  <input type="radio" class="chngRadio" name="radio" value="val2">
  <label for="val2">val2</label>
  <input type="radio" class="chngRadio" name="radio" value="val3">
  <label for="val3">val3</label>
  <input type="radio" class="chngRadio" name="radio" value="val4">
  <label for="val4">val4</label>
</div>
```