# Detect radio input getting unchecked (by clicking another radio input) in Vue

Tags: vuejs2

I want to give my label a border when the radio input is selected but I can only detect when the radio input is being activated. I know it's possible to do this in CSS with some tricks but I want to do it through Javascript.

```
<fieldset>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" @change="someMethod">
    test
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" @change="someMethod">
    test
  </label>
</fieldset>

methods: {
  someMethod () {
    console.log('something')
  }
}
```

I was hoping to call the `someMethod` method when the input state would change between checked and unchcked, but this change is only called when the input is clicked (checked).

https://jsfiddle.net/alucardu/qhbpg2yj/1/

Comment: What do you mean the input would change? It's a radio type, do you mean the label or the unchecked radio?

Comment: The input state. Checked or unchecked. Currently the method is only called when the state changes to checked.

Comment: The solutions are largely written in JQuery, but you might find some inspiration/ help over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838648/onchange-event-handler-for-radio-button-input-type-radio-doesnt-work-as-one

Answer (score 0):

Use $refs to check all the radio inputs and use an array to store the previous state, then we can manage to do it:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
        previous_refs:[],
        
    },
    methods:{
        someMethod(){
        for(const key in this.$refs){
            if(this.previous_refs[key]!==undefined && 
            this.previous_refs[key].checked===true && 
            this.$refs[key].checked===false){
                console.log(this.$refs[key].id+' un-checked, do something');
            }
            if(this.$refs[key].checked===true){
                console.log(this.$refs[key].id+' checked, do something');
            }
            if(this.previous_refs[key]===undefined){
                this.previous_refs[key]={checked:this.$refs[key].checked};
            }
            else{
                this.previous_refs[key].checked=this.$refs[key].checked;
            } 
        }
        
        },
    }
})
```

Please check https://jsfiddle.net/sLw4e0p8/92/ to see details.

Comment: Myea, I wanted to do it in the label itself not in the parent component. I did figure it out through css by the way: https://jsfiddle.net/alucardu/qhbpg2yj/7/

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it through CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/alucardu/qhbpg2yj/7/

Trick was adding a before to the checked input:

```
label {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  input:checked {
    &::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
  }
}
```