# Using javascript to add CSS element when input set to checked

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's my current code:

```
<div class="form-control-switch-option">
    <input type="radio" data-value="Buy">
    <label class="form-control-switch-option-label text-color__dark btns-family">For Sale</label>
</div>

<div class="form-control-switch-option">
    <input type="radio" data-value="Buy" checked="checked">
    <label class="form-control-switch-option-label text-color__dark btns-family">For Sale</label>
</div>
```

What I'm wanting to do is add the class "`working`" to the parent element (`form-control-switch-option`) whenever the `input` element is `checked`.  So, based on the example above, it should become this:

```
<div class="form-control-switch-option">
    <input type="radio" data-value="Buy">
    <label class="form-control-switch-option-label text-color__dark btns-family">For Sale</label>
</div>

<div class="form-control-switch-option working">
    <input type="radio" data-value="Buy" checked="checked">
    <label class="form-control-switch-option-label text-color__dark btns-family">For Sale</label>
</div>
```

Is there any way to do this with pure Javascript (not jQuery)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OnChange event handler for radio button (INPUT type="radio") doesn't work as one value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838648/onchange-event-handler-for-radio-button-input-type-radio-doesnt-work-as-one)

Comment: I saw that one but it appears to be executing after an action takes place, whereas I'm looking for something that does it immediately (no need to click) because `checked` is automatically selected a lot of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will add class working immediately and by interaction.

```
let radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-value="Buy"]')
for (let i = 0; i < radios.length; i ++) {
      // if checked automatically add class 'working'
      if (radios[i].checked) {
          radios[i].parentElement.classList.add('working')
      }
      // add class 'working' by clicking
      radios[i].addEventListener('change', function () {
          this.parentElement.classList.add('working')
      })
}
```

You must use `data-value="buy"` if you want this checkbox to work. if you want to use class, you can change the `querySelectorAll`, for example like

```
document.querySelectorAll('.input-class')
```

the rest is still same