# Doing something if radio button is not checked with js

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do something if the radio button is checked and doing something else if it isn't checked.
if the radio button is checked working well but else statement isn't working and also I don't want to use a ("if-else" ) statement that said if another radio button checked to do something, I just want else statement for doing something if radio button 1 not checked

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="radio" name="layerButton" value="UnTiled" id="raster" >Raster Layer
    <script>
        var radio = document.getElementById('raster');
        radio.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (this.checked) {
         alert("Checkbox is checked..");
        }else{
            alert("Checkbox is not checked..");
        }
});
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: (1) You have multiple elements with the same `id` which is invalid HTML.  Additionally, this begs the question of *which* element you intend to refer to when finding an element by its `id`.  (2) You're binding to the `click` event.  How do you expect to click on a radio button *without* selecting it?  What functionality are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838648/onchange-event-handler-for-radio-button-input-type-radio-doesnt-work-as-one

Comment: IDs need to be unique within an HTML document, you can not use the same ID twice. You only bound an event handler to the first of those radio buttons here because of that. (getElementById will only return the _first_ element it finds, even if you violate the rules of HTML and have more than one.)

Comment: you have added the event on click  and you want the action on document ready or loaded ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a wrapper for both inputs and add the listener to that. Then based on the `checked` status of each `input` you can decide what to do.

```html
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <input type="radio" name="layerButton" value="UnTiled" id="raster">Raster Layer
      <input type="radio" name="layerButton" value="vactor" id="vector"> Vector Layer
    </div>

    <script>
      var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
      wrapper.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
        if (ev.target.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
          if (document.querySelector('#raster').checked) {
            console.log('raster checked');
          } else {
            console.log('raster not checked');
          }
          
          if (document.querySelector('#vector').checked) {
            console.log('vector checked');
          } else {
            console.log('vector not checked');
          }
        }

      });

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add event listener to every radio button and on change of value you can compare the value of the radio button do actions as per your need

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="radio" name="layerButton" value="UnTiled" id="raster" >Raster Layer
    <input type="radio" name="layerButton" value="vactor" id="raster" > Vector Layer
    <script>
    var radio = document.querySelectorAll('[name=layerButton]');
    for(let i = 0; i < radio.length; i++){
        radio[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
          if (this.value === "UnTiled") {
            alert("Checkbox is checked..");
          }else{
            alert("Checkbox is not checked..");
          }
        });
    }
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="radio" name="layerButton" value="UnTiled" id="raster" >Raster Layer
    <script>
    
        var radio = document.getElementById('raster');
      if (!this.checked) {
            alert("Checkbox is not checked..");
        }
        
        radio.addEventListener('change', function() {
        if (this.checked) {
         alert("Checkbox is checked..");
        }else{
            alert("Checkbox is not checked..");
        }
});
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have just added your alert condition of unchecked radio outside the event handler