# Visible the correct dropdown field depending on the radio button selection in laravel blade using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

in my laravel application, I have a form.

In that form, I have one radio button select field and one 2 drop-down fields with the same NAME attribute.

The dropdown should be displayed depending on the radio button's selection.

This is my code so far,

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">

        <div class="form-group">

          
            <strong>Sample Collected :</strong>

            <label for="chkOffice">
            {!! Form ::radio('scb','M', array('class' => 'form-control txt_txt','id'=>'chkOffice','onclick'=>'ShowHideDiv()')) !!}
                    By Office
            </label>        
            
            <label for="chkClient">
            {!! Form ::radio('scb','F', array('class' => 'form-control txt_txt','id'=>'chkClient','onclick'=>'ShowHideDiv2()')) !!}
                    By Client
            </label>          

            {!! $errors->first('scb', '<span class="help-block" role="alert">:message</span>') !!}
                

            {{ Form::select('samp_collected',array_merge(['' => 'Please select a Employee'],  $empId), Request::old('samp_collected'),array('class' => 'form-control txt_txtSelect','id'=>'dvtext')) }}

            {{ Form::select('samp_collected',array_merge(['' => 'Please select a Client'],  $clientId), Request::old('samp_collected'),array('class' => 'form-control txt_txtSelect','id'=>'dvtext2')) }}
            {!! $errors->first('samp_collected', '<span class="help-block" role="alert">:message</span>') !!}
              

        </div>

    </div>
```

And this is my JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHideDiv() {
        var chkOffice = document.getElementById("chkOffice");
        var dvtext = document.getElementById("dvtext");
        alert('office');
        dvtext.style.display = chkOffice.checked ? "block" : "none";
        dvtext2.style.display = chkOffice.checked ? "none" : "none";
    }
    function ShowHideDiv2() {
        var chkClient = document.getElementById("chkClient");
        var dvtext2 = document.getElementById("dvtext");
        alert('client');
        dvtext2.style.display = chkClient.checked ? "block" : "none";
        dvtext.style.display = chkClient.checked ? "none" : "none";
    }
</script>
```

My css goes like this

```
<style type="text/css">
  #dvtext,#dvtext2{
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

But this isn't working and there are no errors in the console as well...

I just need to display the correct dropdown field depending on the radio button selection...

Comment: the event on radio in not working check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838648/onchange-event-handler-for-radio-button-input-type-radio-doesnt-work-as-one)