# How to detect radio button changed in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button

I have a react app where I have a table of radio buttons and I am looping through them

here is my code:

```
const setValue = (item, position) => {
    switch(item[0]) {
        case 'dashboard':
            if(permissions.dashboard == item[1]) {
                return true;
            }
            break;
        case 'user_management':
            if(permissions.user_management == item[1]) {
                return true;
            }
            break;
        case 'users_feedback':
            if(permissions.users_feedback == item[1]) {
                return true;
            }
            break;
        case 'settings':
            if(permissions.settings == item[1]) {
                return true;
            }
            break;
        case 'content_management':
            if(permissions.content_management == item[1]) {
                return true;
            }
            break;
        case 'influencers':
            if(permissions.influencers == item[1]) {
                return true;
            }
            break;
    }
}

const handleChangePermission = (e) => {
    console.log('Handle Change');
}

Object.entries(permissions).map((item, i) => (
     <tr className="permission-row" key={item[0]}>
         <td>{item[0]}</td>
         <td><input type="radio" id={item[0] + i} name={item[0]} defaultChecked={setValue(item, i)}  onChange={(e) => handleChangePermission(e.target.value)}/></td>
         <td><input type="radio" id={item[0] + i} name={item[0]} defaultChecked={setValue(item, i)} onChange={(e) => handleChangePermission(e.target.value)}/></td>
         <td><input type="radio" id={item[0] + i} name={item[0]} defaultChecked={setValue(item, i)}  onChange={(e) => handleChangePermission(e.target.value)}/></td>
     </tr>
))
```

and here what it looks like:
[image]

and this is the permissions object I have:

```
{
"dashboard": 3,
"user_management": 3,
"users_feedback": 3,
"settings": 3,
"content_management": 3,
"influencers": 3
}
```

I have an object with default values called permissions and I am successfully looping through them and displaying the right data. My question is, how do I detect a radio button change, so I can change it in that object `permissions`

Edit:
I added the `onChange` method but still it is not triggering what seems to bet the problem here ??

P.S I'm using `reactstrap` library radio buttons for styling

Comment: The same was as with html: `onChange`

Comment: yeah I did try to implement it but it didn't trigger

Comment: Share what you tried + the source for `CustomInput`.

Comment: I want to clarify something.  Can you post a sample of `permissions` object ? Your are looking to change the  value in `permissions` object when the user changes the selection in radio input right?

Comment: @RifkyNiyas I have updated my question with all necessary

Comment: Please show how `handleChangePermission` is implemented? Also, try adding a console.log there to debug whether or not it is being triggered.

Comment: @SDB_1998 Thank you. Can you please clarify how would you expect the change to happen for example if I click on "dashboard". How do you expect the data to change in the `permissions` object?

Comment: I expect when I click for example from Create And Edit (the second radio button in dashboard) to change the permission in the permissions object to 2 instead of 3 @RifkyNiyas

Comment: Think I got it. If the user clicked on view the value changes to `1`, if the user clicked on create and edit the value changes to `2` and if the user clicked on full access the value changes to `3`. Am I correct?

Comment: yes exactly @RifkyNiyas

Comment: I am working on your answer, can you please include the code for  `setValue`

Comment: @RifkyNiyas done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some fixes to made.

1. Use `onClick` instead of `onChange` event to perform functions with radio buttons.
   [Refer this answer for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9025006/13833218).
2. According to your requirements, the `value` of your radio button should be hardcoded as `value=1`, `value=2`, `value=3` respectively.
3. Modify your `handleChangePermission` as below.

**JSX**

```
  <td>
      <input
          type="radio" id={item[0] + i} 
          name={item[0]} defaultChecked={setValue(item, i)} 
          value="1" onClick={handleChangePermission} />
   </td>
```

**Modified function**

```
const handleChangePermission = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = parseInt(e.target.value);
    permissions[name] = value;
  };
```

Here we simply define the `handleChangePermission` function to accept [synthetic event](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) so we can access the `name` and `value` of radio input button. Since the `name` and `value` of radio button are the same values for the key and value of `permissions` object we can assign access the key and modify the value as above

[Here is the solution on sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-permission-toggler-rf339?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

add the second argument to map(it work like iterator - from 0 to the last element of array - [0,1,2,3,4...] :

```
object.map((number, i) =>
  <li defaultChecked ={() => setValue(item, i)}></li>
);
```

---

to detect change of radio - add just `onChange()` with function:

```
const function = () => {
//your code
}

<CustomInput onChange={() => function} type="radio" id={item[0] + i} name={item[0]} defaultChecked={setValue(item, i)} />
```

Comment: I tried `onChange` isn't triggering. Even if I change the CustomInput to normal html `input` , it is not working

Comment: You tried this syntax: {e => setCurrentValue(e.target.value)}?

Comment: yes, I did and also not triggering. Also, I updated my question so it is much clear now