# Is there an event triggered when a ratio button is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, event-listener

In JavaScript, is there an event triggered when a radio button is checked?

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1">
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" checked>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3">
```

Is something like the following possible?

```
document.getElementById("radio1").addEventListener('checked', () => {
    // Do something when the first radio button is checked
})
```

JSfidde: https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/ko486uqe/2/

PLEASE read before answering or marking as duplicate. My question is not "How to run JS code when the radio button is checked". My question is "Is there an event triggered only when the radio button is checked", this is not exactly the same thing...

Comment: Please, read the documentation and make it a good habit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#technical_summary There's two events: `"input"` and `"change"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OnChange event handler for radio button (INPUT type="radio") doesn't work as one value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838648/onchange-event-handler-for-radio-button-input-type-radio-doesnt-work-as-one)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan @GaryThomas , I already know about `input` and `change` events, my question is not "How to do", my question is "is there another event that is triggered only when the the radio button is checked". But, is seems that no ...

Comment: What advantage would a `checked` event give? How does the default checked state of a radio group get handled?

Comment: No. There's no special event that listens to - radio buttons *only*. This is an [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) if you don't explain what you're actually after with that problem. If you need you generally watch you could attach an `"input"` event listener to `window`, then check if the element that initiated that event was actually a radio button: `if (evt.target.closest("[type='radio']")) { console.log(evt.target.checked) }`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thank you. That's not an XY-problem. I know the alternative options like `if (evt.target ...`.  that was not my question! My final question is clearly written in the title.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such special event for radio buttons only.
There's not such special event for *`"radioChecked"`*.

To test the *checked* state you need to do it on your own.
The best would be to use event delegation, check if the element target is a Radio Element, and then go for its `cehecked` property:

```js
addEventListener(`input`, (evt) => {
  const elRadio = evt.target.closest(`[type="radio"]`);
  if (!elRadio) return; // Not a radio element. Do nothing
  
  console.log(`${elRadio.id} ${elRadio.checked}`); 
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio-group-one" id="radio-1">
<input type="radio" name="radio-group-one" id="radio-2" checked>
<input type="radio" name="radio-group-one" id="radio-3">
```

Whilst using `Event.target.closest()` is always a good practice,  you can also use the `Element.matches()` method when handling actionElements like `input`:

```js
addEventListener(`input`, (evt) => {
  if (!evt.target.matches(`[type="radio"]`)) return; // Do nothing
      
  console.log(`${evt.target.id} ${evt.target.checked}`); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("radio1").addEventListener('change', () => {
    if (document.getElementById("radio1").checked) {
        // Do something when the first radio button is checked
        console.log("radio1 checked");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thx, but this is not the answer to my question, my question is not "how to do", my question is "Is there an event triggered when a ratio button is checked?". I'm already able to write this kind of code